# How do i change from mouse to touch instead?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, color-picker

I uses canvas to create a color picker, and able to get the color code but when i use it in mobile form , i only can tap to choose color. How to i change the code so that when in mobile i can use my finger and drag along the canvas to choose color?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var counterClockwise = false;

for(var angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1){
    var startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;;
    var endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = 'hsl('+angle+', 100%, 50%)';
    context.fill();
}


function createColorWheel(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('picker').getContext('2d');
   ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
       // Set the offset for canvas x and y                                           
    var X =  e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
       var Y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    // Get Image Data Object of pixel currently under crosshair
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(X, Y, 1, 1);
    // Set pixel to the data array (r, g, b, a)
       var pixel = imageData.data; 
    // Add leading zero to number
    // Convert  number to a hexadecimal string with .toString(16)
    // Get the last 2 digits of that string with .slice
    var r = ("0" + (pixel[0]).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    var g = ("0" + (pixel[1]).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    var b = ("0" + (pixel[2]).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    htmlHex = "#"+r+g+b;
    // Change background color of the canvas as the mouse moves
    var previewColor = document.getElementById('picker').style.background = htmlHex;
   });        
}

window.onload = createColorWheel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that mobile device would fire touch event instead of mouse event. In your case, you should use `touchmove` event on mobile device.

You may make your code works for touch event by changing the event listener. Be noted that touch position is retrieved using the `changedTouches` property.

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){                                  
    var X =  e.changedTouches[0].clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var Y = e.changedTouches[0].clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    //........
```

If you need the code to work for multiple platforms, you may need to do some more coding to handle different events on different platforms.

A simple solution to handle cross platform event is to use [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It has a [vmousemove](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousemove/) event which will take care of the cross platform issue.